# C: local pointer variables change after sscanf problem

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a C code that a portion of it is:

```
...
    P *head=NULL,*cur=NULL;
    char Name,tmp[255];
    int AT,ET;
    FILE *iF;

    if((iF=fopen(fileName,"r"))>0){
        fgets(tmp,255,iF);
        sscanf(tmp,"Interval:%d\n",&quantum);
        fgets(tmp,255,iF); //waste

        while(!feof(iF) &&  fgets(tmp,255,iF)){
            sscanf(tmp,"%20c %20d %20d",&Name,&AT,&ET);
...
```

After execution of last sscanf (last line) values of *head & *cur change (they are not NULL anymore!!)
What's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a classic buffer overflow.  You are reading 20 characters into the one byte `Name`, and the extra characters are being written over the space occupied by `head` and `cur` and beyond that, probably trampling the return information that is stored on the stack.  If you printed the values of `head` and `cur` in hex, you'd probably find that the values corresponded to the data entered in `Name`.  For example, if you typed 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' into `Name`, you'd likely find that both `head` and `cur` contained 0x41414141 if you are working on a 32-bit machine.

You need to make `Name` into an array - and you can drop the '&' when you pass it to `sscanf()`.  It might be that you expect:

```
char Name, tmp[255];
```

to declare both Name and tmp as arrays of 255 characters; that is not how C works, though.  The declaration is equivalent to:

```
char Name;
char tmp[255];
```

Comment: I'm running out of reasons to up-vote really nice answers that you provide. So +1, Glad you're here.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation of fopen(). And [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html)